# Sub-Website within a bigger website

Tags: theming

I want to create an entirely new website within a drupal7 website. 

 For example: 
**www.school.edu** will have theme A (not sure if theme's the right word, basically, different looking webpage). And all its subpages and paths will have the same thing. (i.e. www.school.edu/**news**, wwww.school.edu/**about**, www.school.edu/**contact** ... etc). 


#### And, I want a new website within www.school.edu to exist. And that new website should have a different theme.

for example: 
 
**www.school.edu/compsci** will have theme B. And all the subpages that follows under **compsci**/ should all have the same themes; by having a different theme, I mean they will have different headers, different logos, different main menus, different everything, basically entirely new website. (i.e. www.school.edu/**compsci/news**, www.school.edu/**compsci/about**, www.school.edu/**compsci/contact**

I have looked around for answers; it's just that I haven't been able to phrase my question well and I thought if I explained it as such, I would be able to get more accurate answers.

With the code below, I have been able to make each subpage that exist under /compsci to go to page__layout_1 ...

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    $current_page_path = explode('/', request_path());

    if ($current_page_path[0] == 'compsci') {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__layout_1';
    }
}
```

Now, the question is, how I would be able to define different main-menus, different nav-bars, so on. I am quite new to drupal so some terms I am still unfamiliar with -- do I create custom themes or custom modules -- what's the best approach to this?

Comment: I wouldn't initiate a new page for that. I would just switch the theme depending on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different themes using [hook_custom_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x)

```
function HOOK_custom_theme() {
  if(arg(0, drupal_get_path_alias()) == 'compsci') {
    return 'theme_machine_name';
  }
}
```

When you create menus, they will create a block. You can enable the menu blocks on a per-theme basis.

Comment: I was just reading https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-08-26/switching-themes-based-on-current-url#comment-11553759 when I was dropping my comment under the question and all of sudden you answered the question :D

Comment: Half the time when I google something I don't know, I find my own answer to the question somewhere from five years previous that I didn't remember answering, and use that!

Comment: You could make the if a one-liner `if (arg(0, drupal_get_path_alias()) === 'compsci') {`, which I just had to google to find my own answer again!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could pass a path to arg(). I updated accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much guys! I will try it out. Actually, I also saw that post before. I think because it was using node-id, I didn't want it to be node-id dependent.

Comment: I just updated that post as well so it may not confuse others in the same way in the future.

Comment: Hi guys, this is a follow up on this question -- I was wondering how I would be able to specify different front pages for different sites? (i.e. www.school.edu is a front page and www.school.edu/compsci is another front page)?

Comment: This is a new question. You should open a new thread.